# what is the meaning of "locked in a tie"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "locked in a tie" in the following, please?

> Who’s the most accurate shooter in the NBA? Five players were **locked in a tie** for the highest shooting percentage in the league.

Comment: It means there is no possibility for the tie to be broken.  That which cannot be broken is "locked".

Comment: It does not mean that the tie will not be broken.  In fact, given the [context](https://books.google.com/books?id=2k9KAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=Five+players+were+locked+in+a+tie+for+the+highest+shooting+percentage+in+the+league.&source=bl&ots=R88ps1Sqmd&sig=MyQq8hsv_lvSWDU_rmXAcDuFTRs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiut5SUpOrZAhVNLKwKHdFlD-gQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=Five%20players%20were%20locked%20in%20a%20tie%20for%20the%20highest%20shooting%20percentage%20in%20the%20league.&f=false), it's virtually certain that the tie would be broken.  Rather, it simply means that things were "too close to call".

Answer (score 1):

They have the same shooting percentage.

The definition of a **tie** is

> achieve the same score or ranking as another competitor or team.

Example

> They tied for second place.

Comment: But what does "locked in" add to it?

Answer (score 1):

**lock(ed) in** a tie:

*Exclamatory*:  Five players were tied for the highest shooting percentages. Or *idiomatically* they are ever ever so close as competition draws to a close.

> lock into. Fix firmly in position, commit to something. This phrase
>   often occurs as be locked in or into , as in She felt she was locked
>   in a binding agreement. [freedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lock+in)

Comment: If you look at the original context, the "competition" is nowhere near a "close".

Answer (score 1):

The term "locked in" conveys inability to escape, which in turn implies attempts to escape. So this implies that they didn't merely at one time get two scores that were the same, but repeatedly received scores so close together as to remain tied, or close to it.